# mysql: command not found

Tags: terminal, command-line, software, mysql, database

How do I use MySQL from the CLI?  When I use the terminal, I get:

```
Darrens-MacBook-Pro:~ thufir$ 
Darrens-MacBook-Pro:~ thufir$ mysql
-bash: mysql: command not found
Darrens-MacBook-Pro:~ thufir$
```

As you can see, MySQL is installed and running:

[image]

this system:

```
System Software Overview:

  System Version:   OS X 10.10.2 (14C1510)
  Kernel Version:   Darwin 14.1.0
  Boot Volume:  Mac OSx
  Boot Mode:    Normal
  Computer Name:    A MacBook Pro
  User Name:    thufir (thufir)
  Secure Virtual Memory:    Enabled
  Time since boot:  2:08
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Oracle installer for MySQL puts the `mysql` binary in `/usr/local/mysql/bin`. You either need to call it with the full path:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql
```

Or put `/usr/local/mysql/bin` in your `PATH` by adding the following to end of your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:${PATH}
```

And then reloading your shell.

[See my answer to this question for why I think you should install these things with Homebrew](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/177507/292) instead of dmg-based installers. Ultimately, it lets you manage what's in your `PATH` with less hassle.

Comment: my question is why the dmg installer doesn't just add mysql to the path...coming from Linux, that seems broken.

Comment: It's generally not the case that dmg-based installers on OS X modify your `PATH`. There's a very "don't do unexpected things to user's environments" ethos to installer packages on OS X.